# How to implement a custom section in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

We have sections in Robot Framework like below:

```
***Settings***
***Variables***
***Test Cases***
***Keywords***
```

And while running the file Robot framework engine try to find ***TestCases*** and execute it.
Similarly is it possible to create a custom section say ***General*** and when a class is run Keywords/Methods which are defined are executed?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to add sections to a robot file. However, what you describe can be achieved using Robot Framework by filtering the test cased from the command line using [Test Case Tags](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#by-tag-names).

Given the following example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case General 1
    [Tags]    General
    No Operation

Test Case General 2
    [Tags]    General
    No Operation

Test Case Feature 1
    [Tags]    Feature 1
    No Operation

Test Case Feature 2
    [Tags]    Feature 2
    No Operation
```

Starting Robot framework with the argument:

```
--include General
```

Will result in

```
Test Case General 1                                                   | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Case General 2                                                   | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and

```
--include General  --include Feature 2
```

Will result in

```
Test Case General 1                                                   | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Case General 2                                                   | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Case Feature 2                                                   | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: A shorter version of `--include General  --include Feature2` is `-i GeneralORFeature2`. Also, I would try to avoid using spaces in tags.